# How to disable webP optimization only

Tags: apache, caching, mod-pagespeed

I have recently installed mod_pagepeed on my apache server. The problem now is that I have extensive caching and the optimization route to .webp creates massive loads of 404 errors regarding missing images. this is only visible on chrome, opera, and safari. Everything looks ok on firefox and internet explorer (maybe because they don't support webp and call the original image).

I am curious if there is a way to enable all of mod_pagespeed's default optimizations while disabling the webp conversion of images. The paths to these images currently will work sometimes, but will sometimes end up in "not found" errors.

Look at this for example:
https://theorderoftheironphoenix.com/b/the-new-economic-medium-is-knowledge.html 
In EI and Firefox, everything shows. In chrome, opera, and safari, many of the images don't show up.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, you can simply put the following code into your .htaccess:

```
ModPagespeedDisableFilters rewrite_images
```

I will try to figure out the root cause of the issue, but for now, this is a temporary solution which does what I initially asked.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Did you find the root cause of this? As it's still the case.